# VIM-LaTeX - error while trying to open a file with extension tex using vim

Tags: python, vim, vim-latex

when I open any file with extension `tex` using `vim` I get an error below:

```
"test.tex" 1L, 9C
Error detected while processing /Users/user_name/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/texviewer.vim:
line  895:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/user_name/.vim/ftplugin/latex-suite/bibtools.py", line 11, in <module>
    from urllib import urlopen, pathname2url
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/ur
llib.py", line 26, in <module>
    import socket
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/so
cket.py", line 47, in <module>
    import _socket
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/
python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so, 0x0002): code signature in (/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.17_1/Fra
meworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_socket.so) not valid for use in proc
ess: mapped file has no cdhash, completely unsigned? Code has to be at least ad-hoc signed.
```

I use `iTerm` with `zsh` and I've just configured LaTeX so it can be used via `vim` editor using an instruction below:

```
http://vim-latex.sourceforge.net/index.php?subject=download&title=Download
```

I've got installed:

```
Python 2.7.17
```

Is there anyone here who encountered similar issue with `LaTeX`?
I'd really appreciate if someone could help me.

Comment: Hi and welcome! I don't want to sound rude but do yourself a favor and switch from vim-latex to vimtex. vim-latex is extremely bloated and doesn't fit into the modern  vim/neovim architecture. You should also consider to use other more generic plugins like easymotion, ultrasnips, nerdcommenter etc. vim-latex feels like it's writte for emacs.

Comment: This looks like a macOS notarization problem. Maybe related: https://github.com/electron-userland/electron-builder/issues/3940 Since you used homebrew to install python, try updating and/or reinstalling

Comment: Is this still an issue? You should be on Python 3 by now.